# Reliably recognize and handle specific conditions like errors or warnings

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I want to improve the R error handling by providing a function
to handle specific (selected) conditions combined with a retry feature.

For example looped downloads should retry after timeouts or connection errors
but stop immediately in case of other errors.

I cannot find a reliable way to identify a specific condition.

With "reliable" I mean something like a condition ID or at least
different condition classes. My problem is:

1. Error conditions thrown by base R (and also many packages using `stop`)
   seem not to use sub classes but (almost) always return `simpleError`, `error` and `condition` as `class`.
2. Error messages may be localized (different languages) and could even
   change over time with new releases.

How can I reliably recognize a specific condition of base R or 3rd party packages independently of the R versions, platform (Win, OSX, Linux) and language setting?

I assume that I cannot modify the source code that throws the conditions (e. g. to add a sub class).

```
examine_condition <- function(exp) {
  cnd <- tryCatch(exp, error = function(e) e)
  str(cnd)  # show the internals
  invisible(cnd)
}

examine_condition(base::log("a"))
# List of 2
# $ message: chr "non-numeric argument to mathematical function"
# $ call   : language log("a")
# - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"

examine_condition(base::colSums("a"))
# List of 2
# $ message: chr "'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions"
# $ call   : language base::colSums("a")
# - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"

examine_condition(utils::read.csv(file = "this file does not exist.csv"))                  
# List of 2
# $ message: chr "cannot open the connection"
# $ call   : language file(file, "rt")
# - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"

examine_condition(stop("my error"))
# List of 2
# $ message: chr "my error"
# $ call   : language doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
# - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"

library(data.table)
data <- as.data.frame(mtcars)
examine_condition(data[, new_col := 99])  #  ":=" is data.table syntax!
# List of 2
# $ message: chr "Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in pa"| __truncated__
# $ call   : language `:=`(new_col, 99)
# - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"
```

See also:

- [Discussion in 2012 at R-devel regarding "suppress specific warnings"](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2012-October/065089.html)
- [How to ensure english error messages in testthat unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47977951)
- [How to elegantly handle errors in R when state needs to be cleaned up?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17141390)
- [Retry for-loop R loop if error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31999808)
- [R tryCatch handling one kind of error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47198200)

Comment: I think there are changes coming in R-devel that will sub-class errors and such *a little*, but I don't know that they go to the fidelity that you're needing here. I think you're looking for something similar to "exit status" in many shell programs (`curl` has over 90), but I don't think that's readily available, and will certainly be per-`function`. I fear the only locale-aware version will be with `grep` or `%in%` :-(

Comment: @r2evans Yes I heard rumors about improving the condition system too at ERUM 2018. `grep` is my best friend currently ;-) The package `rlang` is providing custom conditions (with sub classing) but this is only possible if the developers are aware of the problem and change the conditions they throw...

Comment: I'm not experienced in coding for locale and internationalization ... but I see the `translations` package, the `gettext` (and related) function, and [Translations30](https://developer.r-project.org/Translations30.html). Instead of `grep`, you might be able to use `gettext` to match the error/warning message, assuming that the author of the function created it with internationalization in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the class of `cnd` and check the kind of error.
Here a little example about download files and how to deal with diferent errors:

```
# Get your items to download
downlodables <- c(paste0('https://www.google.com/', paste0(c('search?q=', '' ), month.name)))

# Iterate over them
for( i in 1:length(downlodables)){

  #Set a 
  dwnl <- tryCatch(download.file(url = downlodables[i], 
                                 destfile = paste0(getwd(),'/', i, '.htm'), 
                                 mode = 'wb'),
                   error = function (e) {e})


  # Check kind of error. Even numbers of 'i'
  class(dwnl) 

  # Check if some error appears
  if (any(class(dwnl) == 'error')){
    # or: any(class(dwnl) %in% c('error', 'warning'))

    # Print your error
    cat(paste0('\n Error found \n', dwnl, '\n'))
    write.csv(cbind(x = i, error = paste0(as.character(dwnl))), file = paste0(i, '.csv'), row.names = FALSE)

    # Conver to string your error
    detailedError <- as.character(dwnl$message) # not necessary

    # Make som in case of denied permisson
    if (any(grep('Permis', detailedError))){
      warning('U shall no pass!')
    }

    # Make som in case of time out conections. In this examlpe try 3 more times the download
    if (any(grep('time', detailedError))){
      count <- 0
      while(count =< 3){

        dwnl <- tryCatch(download.file(url = downlodables[i], 
                                       destfile = paste0(getwd(),'/', i, '.htm'), 
                                       mode = 'wb'),
                         error = function (e) {e})
        if(any(class(dwnl) == 'error')){
          count <- count + 1
        } else { 
          break() 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated code implementing download/retry behaviour in R. Please note that this was just an example in my question and I am asking for a broader solution that is e. g. **not** dependent on the language settings (like it is in your case - `detailedError` is a localized message text). What I need is an even more generic solution to *"How can I reliably recognize a specific condition of base R or 3rd party packages independently of the R versions, platform (Win, OSX, Linux) and language setting?"*

Comment: In the absence of upper- or lower-class levels of error objects, I'll start knowing all posible errors R have. I've search for 'all R errors' with no good results. As you mentionated, grep could allow you categorize the kind of errors ... Is what I can imagne for now